# How to implement chain of string.replaceAll in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a string that I need transform to "canonical" view and for do that I need to call replaceAll() many times on string. I made it work next way:

```
val text = "Java Scala Fother Python JS C# Child"
val replacePatterns = List("Java", "Scala", "Python", "JS", "C#")
var replaced = text
for (pattern <- replacePatterns) {
  replaced = replaced.replaceAll(pattern, "")
}
```

This code is result in replaced = "Fother Child" as I want, but it looks very imperative and I want eliminate accumulator "replaced".
Is there a way in Scala to handle it in one line without var's?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a fold over the list of patterns and the text to be processed as start point:

```
replacePatterns.foldLeft(text){case (res, pattern) => res.replaceAll(pattern, "")}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, Thank you! I thought it should be via foldLeft but wasn't sure in syntax

Comment: No prob. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AndreiMarkhel  BTW, `replaceAll` is a fairly expensive operation to use in a loop. If possible, try to find another way to cleanup the string (like tokenizing).

Comment: or even shorter: `(text /: replacePatterns)(_.replaceAll(_, ""))`